# Operating system for .NET/Python/Java development, with no End Of Life before 2021

Tags: software-development, operating-system

Which OS do you recommend for a software developer used to work with .Net, Python, Java?

Requirements:

- End Of Line not before 2021;
- Easy access to development tools for .Net Core, Java, Python, Lua;
- Standard internet package of e-mail reader and browser;
- No telemetry;
- Access to common messengers such as Skype;
- Remote access capability;
- Home media use to watch movies (different containers such as MKV and MP4 with different encodings, specially with subtitles);
- Easy to use sound devices such as a common pair of speakers and a USB headset;
- A file management tool such as Total Commander, Midnight Commander or similar;
- Possibility to compress/decompress files with different formats (zip, jar, arj, uc2);
- Compatible with [Intel 3970k](https://ark.intel.com/products/70845/Intel-Core-i7-3970X-Processor-Extreme-Edition-15M-Cache-up-to-4-00-GHz-) processor;
- Compatible with SSDs;
- Compatible with GeForce common graphic cards (no need to support top-of-line cards);

Non-solutions:

- Windows 7 not a solution because it approaches its [end-of-life support](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/01/windows-7-enters-its-final-year-of-free-support/) on 2020.
- Windows 10 not a solution because telemetry, forced updates and botched updates.